# Most elegant way to chain Promises/Observables in functional tests

Tags: angular, typescript, protractor, observable

Here is an example of existing test in a project I am working on :

```
AppPage.lastnameInput().clear().then(function () {
  AppPage.lastnameInput().sendKeys(lastname).then(function () {
    AppPage.firstnameInput().clear().then(function () {
      AppPage.firstnameInput().sendKeys(firstname).then(function () {
        AppPage.ibanInput().clear().then(function () {
          AppPage.ibanInput().sendKeys(IBAN).then(function () {
            $('body').click().then(function () {
              callback();
            });
          });
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

It seems to me that this could be flattened. Something like .

```
foo(
  AppPage.lastnameInput().clear(),
  AppPage.lastnameInput().sendKeys(lastname),
  AppPage.firstnameInput().clear(),
  AppPage.firstnameInput().sendKeys(firstname),
  AppPage.ibanInput().clear(),
  AppPage.ibanInput().sendKeys(IBAN),
  $('body').click(),
).then(() => callback())
```

I tried `forkJoin()` but it seems that it does not wait for the first Observable to be complete before executing the next one.

I could implement such function myself but it seems quite generic so I wonder if a more standard function already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`concat()`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/concat) function to execute multiple observables in sequence (rather in parallel as `forkJoin()` works).